# CMake Windows .dll copy after find_package command

Tags: c++, cmake

**Question**
Why .dlls are not copied to the build/Release/ directory as .exe is built?

**Description**

I create a new CMake file with this simple setup:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)
project(use_sort)

find_package(sortdemo REQUIRED)
add_executable(example main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(example PRIVATE sortdemo::my_sort_lib sortdemo::my_print_lib)
```

The project gets configured and installed as x64 Release linked to SHARED libs.
But in Release folder I can only see the .exe, without .dlls.

The libraries my_sort_lib and my_print_lib are my libraries that were installed before in C:\Program Files:
[image]

I do not know if it is necessary, but I also add a link to the CMakeLists of these libraries: https://github.com/petrasvestartas/CMAKE/tree/main/install_export

The full project is here:
https://github.com/petrasvestartas/CMAKE/tree/main/find_package

What I tried:

This does not copy any dlls

```
include(GNUInstallDirs )
install(
    TARGETS "example" 
    RUNTIME_DEPENDENCIES 
    )
```

This gives me error

```
include(GNUInstallDirs )
install(
    TARGETS "example" 
    RUNTIME_DEPENDENCIES "sortdemo::my_sort_lib"
    )
```

Error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:28 (install):
  install TARGETS given unknown argument "sortdemo::my_sort_lib".
```

This gives me error too and not understandable (use this answer from another stackoverflow post)

```
MACRO(INSTALL_ADD_IMPORTED_DLLS target_list target_component destination_folder)
  foreach(one_trg ${target_list})
    get_target_property(one_trg_type ${one_trg} TYPE)
    if (NOT one_trg_type STREQUAL "INTERFACE_LIBRARY")
       get_target_property(one_trg_dll_location ${one_trg} IMPORTED_LOCATION_RELEASE)
       if( one_trg_dll_location MATCHES ".dll$")
          install(FILES ${one_trg_dll_location} DESTINATION ${destination_folder} CONFIGURATIONS Release COMPONENT ${target_component})
       endif()
       get_target_property(one_trg_dll_location ${one_trg} IMPORTED_LOCATION_DEBUG)
       if( one_trg_dll_location MATCHES ".dll$")
          install(FILES ${one_trg_dll_location} DESTINATION ${destination_folder} CONFIGURATIONS Debug COMPONENT ${target_component})
       endif()
    endif()
  endforeach()
ENDMACRO()

set(THIRDPARTY_TARGETS "sortdemo::my_sort_lib" "sortdemo::my_print_lib")

if(MSVC)
    INSTALL_ADD_IMPORTED_DLLS("${THIRDPARTY_TARGETS}" bin bin)
endif()
```

Error

```
Make Error at CMakeLists.txt:28 (get_target_property):
  get_target_property() called with non-existent target "my_sort_lib".
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:44 (INSTALL_ADD_IMPORTED_DLLS)
```

Comment: Starting cmake 3.21 there's the `RUNTIME_DEPENDENCIES` option for [`install(TARGETS)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html#targets). As for the question: Why do you expect them to be copied by default?

Comment: Have you [searched](https://www.google.com/search?q=cmake+install+dll+dependencies+site:stackoverflow.com) existed questions about that topic and have you tried their solutions? E.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68755904/how-to-install-dependent-libraries-with-cmake) or [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44650008/cmake-install-third-party-dll-dependency).

Comment: @Tsyvarev yes as you remember.
Asked on CMake forum, asked you before, I am on this problem for many days, searched Stackoverflow and Googled.

Comment: @fabian I thought if I link libraries they should be copied.
Does the **install(Targets)** must be inside sordemo project or in the use_sort project?

Comment: If you want to make use of the `RUNTIME_DEPENDENCIES` option, you need to specify it for the `install(TARGETS)` command installing the binary the dependencies get linked to (`example`).

Comment: @fabian I tried this line, what has to be written after keyword  RUNTIME_DEPENDENCIES? If I do not write anything, nothing gets copied. If I write "my_sort_lib" I get error.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I tried both of your links nothing works or I do not know how to use them...

Comment: Please, describe (in the question post) what **exactly** have you **tried**: which code you have tried, which error message you got, etc. Otherwise we simply cannot help you aside from repeating those answers again.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Added to questions what I tried.

Comment: As you can see in the first comment, the option `RUNTIME_DEPENDENCIES` appears only in CMake 3.21. Which CMake version do you **actually** use? (the 3.0 version you specified as minimum looks quite old).

Comment: @Tsyvarev cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)

Comment: The option `RUNTIME_DEPENDENCIES` doesn't accept a *target* as a parameter. It collects all dependencies from the targets specified in TARGETS clause.

Comment: @Tsyvarev
Can you write the full code since it is small to make it clear regarding install process of **RUNTIME_DEPENDENCIES**?